# How to push values correctly into an array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, typescript

I want to push some of the values of the following enum

```
enum p {
  XDR = 1,
    PT1M = 2,
    PT1M_ = 2,
    PT5M = 3,
    PT5M_ = 3,
    PT15M = 4,
    PT15M_ = 4,
    PT1H = 5,
    PT1H_ = 5,
    P1D = 6,
    P1D_ = 6,
    P7D = 7,
    P1W = 7,
    P1M = 8,
}
```

using this function

```
private getGMap(): view[] {
  const w = View.getView().getW();
  return widgets.reduce((g, widget) => {
    const granularitySymbol = QueryProcessorService.getWidgetApplied(widget);
    g.push([granularitySymbol, Priority[gSymbol]]);
    return g;
  }, []);
}
```

where `view` is this interface

```
interface view {
  gSymbol: string;
  priority: number;
}
```

I think I am pushing the variables the wrong way. Could someone have a look and help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private getGMap(): view[] {
        const w = View.getView().getW();
        return widgets.reduce((g, widget) => {
          const granularitySymbol = QueryProcessorService.getWidgetApplied(widget);
          g.push([{gSymbol: granularitySymbol, priority: Priority[granularitySymbol]}]);
          return g;
        }, []);

      }
```